# Convert from string to UInt32 - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string-conversion, uint32, uint

I read UInt32 value as a string from XML file. And then I want to convert it to UInt32.

```
UInt32 res = Convert.ToUInt32("0x00B73004", 16);
```

But after converting the resulting value is: `12005380`

Why it is so?

Comment: Do you expect different result? If so, why?

Comment: I am expecting save value: **0x00B73004** so I am a bit confused, it may be that I mixed something...

Comment: @user2653268 you are a bit confused about a value and its rappresentation...

Comment: @user2653268 But you are using `ToUInt32` method. It converts your hexadecimal notation to `UInt32`. For example you can say `int i = 0x00B73004;` which is valid.

Comment: @user2653268 if you have 0x00B73004 and you want 0x00B73004 why do you convert it? :D

Answer (score 4):

It's working just as intended. `0xB73004` (with any number of leading zeroes) is 12005380 in decimal notation.

```
>>> hex(12005380)
'0xb73004'
```

Answer (score 3):

As other answers suggest, the hexidecimal number B73004 equals the decimal number 12005380.

What you might forget is an UInt32 cannot hold any formatting. UInt32 is just a combination of 32 bits which represents a number; a value. How that number is displayed is entirely up to you. You can display it as an hexidecimal, binairy or decimal number. Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {0:X}", res);
```

You can even tell Visual Studio to display the values in hexidecimal format with right-click on the Watch window and select 'Hexidecimal Display'.

This behavior is the same with float point number: It does not contain any information if it should be formatted with a dot or comma. That depends on the (current) culture. 
Also for the DateTime: It contains a date and time, without any formatting. The programmer can define how that date and time should be displayed (For example like: `dd-MM-yyyy` or `yyyy-MM-dd`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

`0x00B73004` is just [hexadecimal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) of `12005380`. Prefix `"0x"` is the most common notation to represents hexadecimal constants.

Since you asking *why* here a math side;

00B73004<sub>16</sub> = **0** * 16<sup>7</sup> + **0** * 16<sup>6</sup> + **B** * 16<sup>5</sup> + **7** * 16<sup>4</sup> + **3** * 16<sup>3</sup> + **0** * 16<sup>2</sup> + **0** * 16<sup>1</sup> + **4** * 16<sup>0</sup>

= 0 + 0 + **11** * 16<sup>5</sup> + **7** * 16<sup>4</sup> + **3** * 16<sup>3</sup> + **0** * 16<sup>2</sup> + **0** * 16<sup>1</sup> + **4** * 16<sup>0</sup>

= 0 + 0 + 11534336 + 458752 + 12288 + 0 + 0 + 4

= 12005380

By the way B<sub>hex</sub> = 11<sub>dec</sub>

You can save this hexadecimal notation in a numeric value like;

```
uint i = 0x00B73004;
```

Nothing wrong with that. You can see it's [base 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) value on debugger.

[image]